# How to stop class of active in sidebar navigation in loop

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, sidebar

I have coded a sidebar navigation and added loop in `<li>` for brand class. which has extracted from database!

Below is the code of Sidebar Navigation.

Problem is `<li class='active'>` has enabled with all li. i only wanted to enable to active with opened page of site. How to break down li using loop?

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <nav class="nav-sidebar">
        <ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="<?php echo(BASE_URL); ?>index.php">Home</a></li>
            <?php
            try {

                $brands = Brand::get_brands();
                foreach ($brands as $b) {

                    echo("<li class='active'><a href='" . BASE_URL . "products/products.php?brandID=$b->brandID'>$b->brand_name</a></li>");
                }
            } catch (Exception $ex) {
                echo("<li>" . $ex->getMessage() . "</li>");
            }
            ?> 

            <li class="nav-divider"></li>
            <li><a href="<?php echo(BASE_URL); ?>login.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></i> Sign in</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Image of sidebar screenshot: [Sidebar Navigation Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DInpH.png)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the links you make, I assume that your URL looks something like `yoursite.com/products/products.php?brandID=150`. You can use the brandID from the URL by calling `$_GET['brandID']`.

So we check if it is set and compare the value to the brandID inside the loop.

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <nav class="nav-sidebar">
        <ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="<?php echo(BASE_URL); ?>index.php">Home</a></li>
            <?php
            try {

                $brands = Brand::get_brands();
                foreach ($brands as $b) {
                    // adding this line:
                    $class = ( isset($_GET['brandID']) and $_GET['brandID'] == $b->brandID) ? ' class="active"' : '';
                    echo("<li".$class."><a href='" . BASE_URL . "products/products.php?brandID=$b->brandID'>$b->brand_name</a></li>");
                }
            } catch (Exception $ex) {
                echo("<li>" . $ex->getMessage() . "</li>");
            }
            ?> 

            <li class="nav-divider"></li>
            <li><a href="<?php echo(BASE_URL); ?>login.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></i> Sign in</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: My explanation is in the answer. When you browse to one of the items, the URL becomes for example `yoursite.com/products/products.php?brandID=150`. We can get the value `brandID=150` by calling `$_GET['brandID']`. So what you do inside your loop is get that value and check if it is the same as the `$b->brandID` that is looped in that moment. If it is, add the class, if not add nothing.

Comment: its works fine, i just wanted to find logic! thanks lot for your kind reply!